# Heroku Review App Error, but works fine on production app in pipeline

Tags: node.js, heroku, pipeline, pull-request

When using the Heroku Pipelines, I'm encountering errors on Review Apps that are automatically generated even though when pushing the same code to master the resulting production app appears to deploy just fine.

The application appears to run from master in the pipeline, but the PR's that trigger the Review Apps don't appear to run and result in the following error:

```
Invalid Buildpack heroku/node.js
```

The app.json is the what defines the buildpack for production:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "env": {
  },
  "formation": {
  },
  "addons": [

  ],
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "heroku/node.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversely to the Heroku documentation, the url should be:

```
"urn:buildpack:heroku/nodejs"
```

Directly after asking the question here on SO, I found some other apps that used that and making that change appeared to work in the Review Apps.

Hope this helps others experiencing the same issue, and maybe Heroku will update docs and/or allow the documented way to function for Review Apps.